# 「国や国といった留学生が多い」？

Tags: usage, semantics

I came across a sentence on a Japanese grammar site that strikes me as somewhat odd.

> この学校には中国やベトナムといった留学生が多い。 ([source](https://japanese-teacher.tanosuke.com/2019/01/12/toitta/))

Shouldn't it be

> この学校には中国**人**やベトナム**人**といった留学生が多い。

because countries can't be students, can they?

My google fu led me to this sentence. Does it mean this structure is fine?

> 介護や不動産関連など7社、ベトナムやタイといった留学生約30人が参加した。([source](https://www.sankei.com/life/news/171107/lif1711070014-n2.html))

Comment: Something I've pondered myself. I've always seen といった appear with strictly proper nouns. 中国生 would be 'students from China' and not China itself (so it's technically not a proper noun). It also helps to interpret といった as 'here are some examples' in this context instead of seeing it as similar to という perhaps?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> この学校には中国やベトナムといった留学生が多い。
> ベトナムやタイといった留学生約30人が参加した。

I also find them a little strange. Grammatically speaking, I think they are incorrect. I would probably write them as something like...

> この学校には中国やベトナム**などからの**留学生が多い。
> この学校には中国やベトナムといった**国からの**留学生が多い。
> ベトナムやタイ**などからの**留学生約30人が参加した。
> ベトナムやタイといった**国からの**留学生約30人が参加した。